# probability of number of $S_n\geq 0$ equals $\infty$

Tags: probability

Let $\{X_n\}$ i.i.d. such that $EX_1=-1$. Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ for all $n\geq 1$, and let $T$ be the total number of $n\geq 1$ satisfying $S_n\geq 0$. Compute $P[T=\infty]$.

By Kormogolov's 0-1 law I guess it is $0$, and by Strong Law of Large Number it can be proved easily, however $E|X_1|$ might not exist and I don't know how to do if $E|X_1|=\infty$.

Comment: How can $\mathbb{E}X_1=-1$ if $\mathbb{E}\lvert X_1\rvert=\infty$ or does not exist?

Comment: You declared $E[X_1]=-1$ initially.

Comment: If $EX_n=-1$ then $E|X_1|<\infty$.

Comment: If $E[X]$ exists, then by definition, that means that $E|X|<\infty$. In particular, sinec $EX_1=-1$, we know $E|X_1|<\infty$. Please refer back to the definition of expected value to understand this.